# Protobuf enum message with value as string in php

Tags: php, enums, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf emun that I use as a field in another message. I've also add a custom option to this enumeration to set a text-version value for each option

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

package Message;

extend google.protobuf.EnumValueOptions {
    optional string name = 10001;
}
enum ScreenshotStatus {
    UNKNOWN = 0 [(name) = "unknown"];
    IN_QUEUE = 1 [(name) = "in_queue"];
    PROGRESSING = 2 [(name) = "[progressing"];
    FINISHED = 3 [(name) = "finished"];
    RUNNING = 4 [(name) = "running"];
}
```

However, when I generate php classes for protobufs I get plain old class without any methods to get enum name.

```
class ScreenshotStatus
{
    /**
     * Generated from protobuf enum <code>UNKNOWN = 0 [(.Message.name) = "unknown"];</code>
     */
    const UNKNOWN = 0;
}
```

Is there a way to get a name value for a ScreenshotStatus::UNKNOWN and vice versa - get proper enum by its name "unknown".